# What are the correct tags and properties to select?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl a web site (http://theschoolofkyiv.org/participants/220/dan-acostioaei) to extract artist's name and biography only. When I define the tags and properties, it comes out without any text, which I want to see.

I am using scrapy to crawl the web site. For other websites, it works fine. I have tested my codes but it seems I can not define the correct tags or properties. Can you please have a look at my codes?

This is the code that I used to crawl the website. (I do not understand why stackoverflow enforces me to enter irrelevant text all the time. I have already explained what I wanted to say.)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from artistlist.items import ArtistlistItem

class ArtistlistSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "artistlist"
    allowed_domains = ["theschoolofkyiv.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://theschoolofkyiv.org/participants/220/dan-acostioaei']
    enter code here
    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath("//div[@id='participants']")
        for titles in titles:
            item = ArtistlistItem()
            item['artist'] = response.css('.ng-binding::text').extract()
            item['biography'] = response.css('p::text').extract()
            yield item
```

This is the output that I get:

```
{'artist': [],
 'biography': ['\n                ',
               '\n                ',
               '\n            ',
               '\n                ',
               '\n                ',
               '\n            ']}
```

Comment: If you analyze the `Network` tab of the browser, you'll understand that the website is using a `GET` request to fetch data about the artist. This is the URL is being used for this purpose: http://theschoolofkyiv.org/wordpress/wp-json/posts/220, here in this URL, **220** might be some ID related to the artist record, so from the main URL which you have mentioned above, you can get this ID.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I was not aware of that. Your comment helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple illustration (assuming you already know about AJAX request mentioned by [Tony Montana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260154/tony-montana)):

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
from artistlist.items import ArtistlistItem

class ArtistlistSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "artistlist"
    allowed_domains = ["theschoolofkyiv.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://theschoolofkyiv.org/participants/220/dan-acostioaei']

    def parse(self, response):
        participant_id = re.search(r'participants/(\d+)', response.url).group(1)
        if participant_id:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url="http://theschoolofkyiv.org/wordpress/wp-json/posts/{participant_id}".format(participant_id=participant_id),
                callback=self.parse_participant,
            )

    def parse_participant(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        item = ArtistlistItem()
        item['artist'] = data["title"]
        item['biography'] = data["acf"]["en_participant_bio"]
        yield item
```

Comment: Dear @Tony Montana, that works very fine for me. Thank you so much. Erdal Ayan